# FluentValidation automatic validation not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am using fluentvalidation in my .net core web api project. But it is not added automatically, where could I be making a mistake. ?

.net core 7.0
FluentValidation.AspNetCore 11.2.2

```
 builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
 {
   options.Filters.Add(new ValidateFilterAttribute()); 
 });
 builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
 {
  options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
 });
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
 builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
 builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Contents of the CompanyUpdateDtoValidator.cs file

```
public class CompanyUpdateDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<CompanyUpdateDto>
{
    public CompanyUpdateDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} This field is required..").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} This field is required..");
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} This field is required.").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} This field is required..");
        RuleFor(x => x.BusinessCode).NotNull().WithMessage("{PropertyName} This field is required..").NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} This field is required..");
    }
}
```

FluentValidation has made a change as follows.
https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1965

Contents of ValidateFilterAttribuate

```
public class ValidateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(CustomResponseDto<NoContent>.Fail(400, errors));
        }
    }
}
```

But I am sending a missing json as below, but fluentvalidation is not returned to me.

```
 {
   "id": 0,
   "name": "Test 123"
 }
```

This field "BusinessCode" is required but missing, I'm sending it to test, but it doesn't give a return error

I can't find where am I doing wrong

Comment: Is the `CompanyUpdateDtoValidator` class in the same assembly? You can try this as well `builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CompanyUpdateDtoValidator>();`

Comment: Yes this method works but I have hundreds of validatorDto files I don't want to add them all one by one

Comment: If they are in the same assembly as `CompanyUpdateDtoValidator` they will be added as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have:

```
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

This assumes that your validators are in the same assembly as the `Program.cs` which might not be the case.

If all of your validators are in the same assembly you can use:

```
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CompanyUpdateDtoValidator>();
```

If they are not in the same assembly, you will have to register one validator per assembly suing the above line of code.

Comment: it works with this method, i tried before, but i have thousands of files, i can't add them all one by one

Comment: @byfth Are they in the same assembly/project? If they are they will be added automatically.

Comment: yes in the same directory but by no means fluentvalidation is working.